# ImportError: cannot import name and Cannot import class

Tags: python, django, import

I got a full code from github and everything was OK, server worked without any problems. But then I tried to do some changes, like adding a new class in the `model.py` and trying to import it to the `admin.py` I got such an error:

> ImportError: cannot import name TechnicalExamination.

Of course, I did migrations before this, using `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

Here is my class in models.py:

```
class HealthExamination(models.Model):
class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Health Examinations'

doctor = models.CharField(max_length=70)
person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
start_date = models.DateField()
end_date = models.DateField()

class TechnicalExamination(models.Model):
  class Meta:
    verbose_name_plural = 'Technical Examinations'

  technician = models.CharField(max_length=70)
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  start_date = models.DateField()
  end_date = models.DateField()

def get_fields(self):
    pairs = []
    for field in self._meta.fields:
        name = field.name
        try:
            pairs.append((name, getattr(self, "get_%s_display" % name)()))
        except AttributeError:
            pairs.append((name, getattr(self, name)))
    return pairs

def __str__(self):
  return str(self.person)
```

Here is my admin.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Person, Car, InsuranceCompany, Policy,   HealthExamination, TechnicalExamination

admin.site.register(Person)
admin.site.register(Car)
admin.site.register(InsuranceCompany)
admin.site.register(Policy)
admin.site.register(HealthExamination)
admin.site.register(TechnicalExamination)
```

And here is my root:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like `TechnicalExamination` is not defined on the same level as the other classes.

Comment: TechnicalExamination is on the models.py, like HealthExaminations. But the first one doesn't work, and the second one does.

Comment: Sure, but `def __str__` is not indented correctly in the question, so can you please show at least two models in the file? One that works and that one?

Comment: I've edited my question. HealthExamination works and TechnicalExamination doesn't.

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code. What you have posted currently would not run at all.

Comment: __PLEASE__ fix your code snippet indentation to exactly match your models code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check migration file - you should have operations contain CreateModel your TechnicalExamination

   ```
   operations = [
       migrations.CreateModel(
           name='TechnicalExamination',
   ...
   ```

   If something wrong with migration files, remove migrations directory and makemigration again (You might need to clear your database , too) or use `--fake`
2. import from django shell:

   ```
   $python manage.py shell
   > from your_app_name.models import TechnicalExamination
   ```

If not imported, you can see more detail error messages and debug it.

3. Try import by `from destrict_office.models import TechnicalExamination`

I experienced some problems with `.models` import method, and it's not clear import method.

Comment: Also there's some possibility for recursive import, but I couldn't see any code provoking recursive import. Check your models.py that there's no recursive import one from other model